# Order of answers

Tags: discussion

Imagine there's a great answer to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns/29195706#29195706), but people keep answering new answers. These new answers are worse, and the votes reflect that.

Why does the old (but gold) answer stay *so far* below? Does the algorithm really do *Accepted first*, and then orders by (date, votes) lexicographically?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the old (but gold) answer stay so far below?

It doesn't, unless you've explicitly request that answers be sorted that way.

By default, the sort is *accepted first, then score*, ie "votes". You've probably changed your sort to "oldest".

[image]

Comment: You are right, I have "active" selected (and never actively noticed that option, so my changing probably came from mindless playing around in a tired midnight session).